# CloudFlare SSL refused on HTTP access

Tags: ssl, cloudflare

I not use CloudFlare SSL , but use LetsEncrypt in my webserver nginx.

I'm trying to disable ssl cloudflare default, but not work. Website when access http://example.com result on "Connection refused" and when accesss with [http://www.example.com](http://example.com) shows

> Error 521 Web server is down

What i have to do? thanks